# How to fix Python rounding error in Floating Point numbers without using decimal, fractions or any other external libraries?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding-error

I've got a class Simulator:

```
class Simulator: # we use a class just to hold variables between calls
    def __init__(self):
        # initialise accumulators
        self.a_sum = 0
        self.b_sum = 0
        
    def update(self, a, b):
        # increment
        self.a_sum += a
        self.b_sum += b
       
    def results(self):
        # return a  pair of results
        return self.a_sum, self.a_sum - self.b_sum
```

where if I print the result

```
a_error, d_error = simulate(Simulator())
print(f"Error in a_sum is {a_error} and {d_error} in d_sum")
```

I get `Error in a_sum is 13.7734375 and 4.101232676410264e-08 in d_sum`, which is caused by using floating point numbers. I know how the calculations work, but I was wondering whether it would be possible to fix the error without converting to decimal? I've tried rounding:

```
def update(self, a, b):
        # increment
        self.a_sum += round(a, 3)
        self.b_sum += round(b, 3)
```

which got the error to slightly lower numbers: `Error in a_sum is 5.375 and 4.101232676410264e-08 in d_sum` but I couldn't get it any lower after that.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want better results summing floating-point numbers, put them in a list and call `math.fsum()` on the list (and if you count `math` as using an *external library* then that is too bad). That will give you a result that is close to the best that can be achieved given that floating-point numbers have finite precision. You are up against a hardware limitation and there is no way to "fix" it.

Comment: I haven't thought of using fsum(), will certainly try! Thanks @BoarGules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How to fix Python rounding error in Floating Point numbers without using decimal, fractions or any other external libraries?*

[Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

> (...)there are many different decimal numbers that share the same
> nearest approximate binary fraction. For example, the numbers `0.1` and
> `0.10000000000000001` and
> `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` are all
> approximated by `3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55`. Since all of these
> decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be
> displayed while still preserving the invariant `eval(repr(x)) == x`.(...)**this is in the very nature of binary floating-point**: this is
> not a bug in Python, and it is not a bug in your code either. You’ll
> see the same kind of thing in all languages that support your
> hardware’s floating-point arithmetic (although some languages may not
> display the difference by default, or in all output modes).

emphasis added by me, so I suppose only way to repair `float` in this case is to not use `float` at all. Which is generally not feasible without *decimal, fractions or any other external libraries*.